# iphone photo crop

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

i am implementing photoalbum and i want to select image from album and then go to edit image page and crop image like iphone do like make rectangle and show matrix same like in iphone 4s and i can resize that but i only see a big rectangle
i use this code

```
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate=(id)self;
    picker.allowsEditing=YES;

    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

and this delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Check this [example](https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper) . hope its works for you..